# MySQL Tables for School Website

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Right now I have 40+ tables for my website and I don't think I'm using MySQL to it's full power quite right. I am making a website similar to Moodle. It basically just holds tests for students grouped by courses.

**Origonal Tables**:

```
courses - Lists all courses (ID, Name)
c_$id   - Lists all the Tests (ID, Name, etc) for course number $id
a_$id   - Lists all questions for the test number $id (Question, A, B, C, D)
g_$id   - Lists all grades for the course with course number $id.
c_a     - Lists course ID and assignment ID pairs ex: (1,2) (1,3) (2,2) (2,3)
```

**Tables Revision 1:**

```
courses   - Lists all courses (ID, Name, etc)
tests     - Lists all tests (ID, Name, etc)
questions - Lists all questions from all tests (ID, Ques, Ans)
grades*   - Lists all grades (studentID, courseID, testID, grade)
students* - Lists all students and their courses (StudentID, courseID)
```

The grades* table, it's basically 3 primary keys and a value. Something seems odd about it. Is there a better way? Same goes for the students table. Both are basically connections of the other tables. Primary key for fast searching is not possible?

**Origonal Post:**

What is the most efficient way to recreate this to utilize the power of MySQL?

As of right now when a new course is made it creates a new table for that course (`c_$id`), then a table for each assignment and a list of grades for that course `g_$id`. Then when creating an assignment it creates a new `a_$id` table,adding that course and assignment pair to `c_a`.

I have removed the "`*`" from most of my select statements and added "`LIMIT 1`" to any that are selecting a primary key, next is solving this OOP issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In gerneral, it is better to stick to a static scheme (i.e. a fixed set of tables and columns) where possible. So instead of encoding connections into the table names, use a separate column to reference other tables. For example, instead of separate `c_$id` *tables* holding the tests for each course, you would have a `tests` *table* with a `course_id` *column*. When entering a test, you'd fill in the `course_id` value to denote which course this test belongs to. When retrieving data, you could

```
SELECT …
FROM courses, tests
WHERE courses.id = tests.course_id
```

One benefit of using only a fixed set of table names is that you can use [prepared statements](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in your PHP code, using placeholders (usually `?`) instead of the actual values. You can [pass values](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) when you [execute](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) the query, and the server will ensure that they get [escaped](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) properly. This prevents most [SQL injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issues. Furthermore, executing the same prepared statement repeatedly with different values might give a performance gain, as the query has to be parsed, analyzed and optimized but once.

Adding `LIMIT 1` to queries that can only return a single row is unlikely to yield any performance gain: the MySQL optimizer knows about primary keys, so it can tell this fact just as well. As these lines *might* make your queries slightly harder to read and maintain, consider omitting them again.

Comment: Your right about the static scheme, that will cut down on this organization monster I have created as well as allow indexing to do what it does best and boost the speed of my queries. Thanks!

Is the above edit like you are suggesting?

Comment: @CoderWalker: It depends on what you want to model. The original tables had tests associated to courses. The new model has tests as independent entities. In the latter case, you can use the same test for multiple courses. Is that intended? If not, then a courseID in the tests table would be useful, as my example indicated. In general, your edit asks a number of new questions, which might be better handled in follow-up posts. E.g. you can ask how to create primary keys spanning multiple columns (which is possible). Tables with multiple foreign keys are quite common to express n:m relations.